# Remove parent element and keep the content

Tags: javascript, html

Suppose I have already get the table with JavaScript like this:

```
 var isert = inn.getElementsByTagName("table");
```

and I've got a structure like this:

```
<table width="100%">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><div class="extra"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><div class="extra"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><div class="extra"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here, how can I remove the outside Table structure, and keep the content only, so that result of the extracted code should be:

```
<div class="extra"></div>
<div class="extra"></div>
<div class="extra"></div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason this method is being employed as opposed to simply editing the source file appropriately? Is this a third party control being rendered or some other inaccessible code base?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
function removeTo(from, what) {
    if (!from || !what) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        els = from.getElementsByTagName(what);
        while (els[0]) {
            from.parentNode.insertBefore(els[0],from);
        }
        from.parentNode.removeChild(from);
    }
}

removeTo(document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0], 'div');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/XhBA4/).

Incidentally:

```
var isert = inn.getElementsByTagName("table");
```

Doesn't give you a reference to the `table` element, it gives you a nodeList of *all* the `table` elements within the `inn` variable (whatever that might be). To *act* on a particular `table` you need to specify which *particular* `table` you want to act upon, which is why, above, I've used `document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But if I have known that current table element contains multiple div and need to apply removeTo() function, is `removeTo(this, 'div');` right?

Comment: If `this` refers to the element from which the elements should be removed, then yes.